# StreamBuilder Widget is not rendered if nested in children: <Widget>[]

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am trying to read data from Firebase's FireStore database and show as a list in flutter app.

I came across this issue where I need to make **StreamBuilder** part of Widget Array. If the **StreamBuilder** widget is as a single child of a widget, it renders okay. But if part of an Array of child widgets, it doesn't work. e.g.

Below is my Widget that uses **StreamBuilder**

```
Widget postsListWidget = new StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          return new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            itemExtent: 55.0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
          );
        });
```

Here is me using StreamBuilder widget with a single Child parent e.g. Container

```
return new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
      child: postsListWidget,
    )
```

The above code would work properly because **Container** has only a single 'child' element.

However, if I user another widget which can have more than one children, e.g. Row, the **StreamBuilder** will not render. e.g.

```
 return new Scaffold(
        body: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[postsListWidget],
    )
```

The above code will not render the StreamBuilder Widget.

I get the following errors in my debug window

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#9162d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#9162d NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Tried to paint a RenderObject reentrantly.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 213 pos 15: 'data != null': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Tried to paint a RenderObject reentrantly.
```

I 'll appreciate if someone could help, I just couldn't find Google to help on this one!!

Comment: `Widget postsListWidget = new StreamBuilder(` looks suspicious. What are you doing with `postsListWidget`?

Comment: I am trying to get the stream from firebase FireStore database and showing in a list. Since it wasn't working under Row->Children Array, I created a separate widget for the posts from database i.e. postsListWidget !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing checks for errors and data not yet available like shown in

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

> ```
> new StreamBuilder<int>(
>   stream: _lot?.bids, // a Stream<int> or null
>   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
>     if (snapshot.hasError)
>       return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
>     switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
>       case ConnectionState.none: return new Text('Select lot');
>       case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Awaiting bids...');
>       case ConnectionState.active: return new Text('\$${snapshot.data}');
>       case ConnectionState.done: return new Text('\$${snapshot.data} (closed)');
>     }
>   },
> )
> ```